# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Пытаюсь написать парсер (впервые в жизни). Вот пытаюсь сделать поиск на "Чемпионате"
Выдает ошибку

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

Похоже что то не так

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('div',class_='livetable zbyqj js-livetable')
    print(table.prettify())
print(parse(get_html('https://www.championat.com/')))
```

Comment: в `BeautifulSoup(html)` допишите аргумент `lxml` `BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")`

Comment: Не помогло. Может я неправильно ищу?

Comment: очевидно, что table у вас None  (find() ничего не нашёл). Возьмите минимальный кусок html, который искомый div содержит, откройте Python REPL и интерактивно попробуйте поискать, используя разные аргументы. Если не получится, то добавьте в вопрос этот кусок html, уберите urlopen() (замените на `return html_str`) и явно словами укажите какой конкретно элемент хотите найти¶ Здесь лучше `select()` метод использовать, чтобы о порядке, количестве классов не думать. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: А какая конкретно  нужна информация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}

url = "https://www.championat.com/"

def parser():
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content

        item = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

        data =  item.find('div', {'class': 'livetable-bar tabs js-livetable-bar'}).prettify()

        text =  item.find('a', {'href': '/stat/'}).text

        print(data)
        print(text)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Нет соединения с интернетом...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser()
```